# Why is the associated type Output in trait std::future::Future shown as [async output]?

Tags: rust, future

Method 1 (WORKS):

```
pub fn spawn_good<F, R>(future: F) -> JoinHandle<R>
where
    F: Future<Output = R> + 'static + Send,
    R: Send + 'static,
{
    let (sender, recvr) = oneshot::channel();
    let future = async move {
        sender.send(future.await);
    };

    let task = Arc::new(Task {
        state: AtomicUsize::new(0),
        future: Mutex::new(Box::pin(future)),
    });

    Box::pin(async { recvr.await.unwrap() })
}
```

Method 2 (DOESN'T WORK):

```
pub fn spawn_bad<F, R>(future: F) -> JoinHandle<R>
where
    F: Future<Output = R> + 'static + Send,
    R: Send + 'static,
{
    let (sender, recvr) = oneshot::channel();
    let future = async move {
        sender.send(future.await);
    };

    let future = Mutex::new(Box::pin(future));

    let task = Arc::new(Task {
        state: AtomicUsize::new(0),
        future,
    });

    Box::pin(async { recvr.await.unwrap() })
}
```

```
expected struct `std::sync::Mutex<Pin<Box<(dyn futures::Future<Output = ()> + std::marker::Send + 'static)>>>`
   found struct `std::sync::Mutex<Pin<Box<impl futures::Future<Output = [async output]>>>>`
```

Task definition:

```
struct Task {
    state: AtomicUsize,
    future: Mutex<Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = ()> + Send>>>
}
```

JoinHandle definiton:

```
type JoinHandle<T> = Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = T> + Send>>;
```

I don't see why the second method won't work. The only difference is an additional allocation. Is there some kind of nuance with `Mutex` I am missing?

Comment: Can you link to a Playground that shows the `[async output]` error? I tried to reproduce it but am getting a [slightly different error message](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=febba6905e1bd68df733982307ce6e37).

Comment: Can't get a link to a playground, perhaps i'll change the question to be about opaque type message because that is common on both playground and my IDE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72481994/method-returning-dyn-fails-to-compile-if-the-return-value-is-assigned-to-a-varia/). When you assign `future` to the newly created `Task`, and since `Task::future` is of type `Mutex<Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = ()> + Send>>>`, this becomes a constraint for type inference: `future` should have type `Mutex<Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = ()> + Send>>>`.

Now, `future` actually has the type `Mutex<Pin<Box<[some future generated by async block]>>>` (let's name `[some future generated by async block]` `Fut` from now), **not** `Mutex<Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = ()> + Send>>>`. `Pin<Box<Fut>>` can *coerce* to `Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = ()> + Send>>` (and also `Box<Fut>` can coerce to `Box<dyn Future<Output = ()> + Send>`), but will do so only if the compiler deems this is necessary. On the other hand, `Mutex<Pin<Box<Fut>>>` **cannot** coerce to `Mutex<Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = ()> + Send>>>`, because coercion isn't recursive (`T` can coerce to `U` doesn't mean `A<T>` can coerce to `A<U>`).

The important point is, the compiler only checks whether a coercion should be performed at special [coercion sites](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html#coercion-sites). Instantiation of a struct is a coercion site for each field expression, and so are method calls, but variable declarations `let` statement without an explicit type are not coercion sites. We can follow the compiler inference:

For the first, working case:

The expression provided for `Task::future` should have type `Mutex<Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = ()> + Send>>>`, i.e. this is its *expected type* (or, the compiler has an *[`Expectation`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/357bc27904d4a99c83d4b01272c34e0e54934fa5/compiler/rustc_typeck/src/check/expectation.rs#L11)* for it to be of that type).

Since `Mutex::new()` has the signature `fn<T>(T) -> Mutex<T>`, and we know it should return `Mutex<Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = ()> + Send>>>`, we can conclude that the value of `T` is `Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = ()> + Send>>`. So, its parameter also should have that type, or this is its expected type.

Ditto for `Box::pin()`, with a signature of `fn<T>(T) -> Pin<Box<T>>`. Now `T` is `dyn Future<Output = ()> + Send`. We do not provide a value of that type: we provide a value of type `Fut`. But don't give up! Let's trace back and try to find a good coercion. `Fut` cannot be coerced to `dyn Future<Output = ()> + Send` directly, but if we go back one step, we see `Pin<Box<Fut>>` that *can* be coerced to `Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = ()> + Send>>`. This is inside a method call (`Mutex::new()`) so it can be coerced here. Problem solved.

Now let's follow the second case:

First, we infer the type for the `future` variable. We have no expectation for it, because no type is specified. We have no expectation for `T` in `Mutex::new()` or the one in `Box::pin()` either. So we can conclude from the value that `T` for `Box::pin()` is `Fut`, and then `T` for `Mutex::new()` is `Pin<Box<Fut>>`. Thus `future` has type `Mutex<Pin<Box<Fut>>>`.

Now, when trying to type-check the expression for the field `future`, we notice it has type `Mutex<Pin<Box<Fut>>>` while its expected type is `Mutex<Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = ()> + Send>>>`. We cannot coerce the first to the second, but neither we can propagate the coercion, because `let` is not a coercion site. So we declare an error.

The fix is simple: you should insert a coercion site. You can either specify the type for the `let future`, and make the compiler coerce it there, or specify `as _` after `Box::pin()` (`Mutex::new(Box::pin(future) as _)`, of course specifying the type will also work), forcing the compiler to put a coercion site there (this is quite confusing, because method calls are already coercion sites, but by default the compiler doesn't coerce there because it infers `T` by the parameter. Putting `as _` there is like telling the compiler "Stop! I want to disconnect the return type from the argument's type, it is not necessarily `Pin<Box<[parameter type]>>`, it only should be coercible (castable, to be precise) to it!").