# Rust: can't collect an `Iterator<Item = Box<Dog>>` into `Vec<Box<dyn Animal>>`

Tags: rust, trait-objects

I feel like this code should work since `Box<Dog>`s are supposed to be able to be implicitly converted into `Box<dyn Animal>`s in most situations:

```rust
struct Dog {}
trait Animal {}
impl Animal for Dog {}

fn main() {
    let _: Vec<Box<dyn Animal>> = [Dog {}, Dog {}]
        .into_iter()
        .map(Box::new)
        .collect();
}
```

However, I get the following compiler error:

```rust
error[E0277]: a value of type `Vec<Box<dyn Animal>>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `Box<Dog>`
    --> src/main.rs:9:10
     |
9    |         .collect();
     |          ^^^^^^^ value of type `Vec<Box<dyn Animal>>` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=Box<Dog>>`
     |
     = help: the trait `FromIterator<Box<Dog>>` is not implemented for `Vec<Box<dyn Animal>>`
     = help: the trait `FromIterator<T>` is implemented for `Vec<T>`
note: required by a bound in `collect`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
```

I also tried inserting a `.map(Into::into)` to convert the `Box<Dog>`s into `Box<dyn Animal>`s, but that gives the error `` the trait bound `Box<dyn Animal>: From<Box<Dog>>` is not satisfied ``.

So how am I supposed to collect my `Box<Dog>`s into `Box<dyn Animal>`s?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're almost there. The problem is that `Box::new()` takes `T` and gives `Box<T>`. No coercion is possible.

Instead, you should provide a closure `|v| Box::new(v)`, but even that is not enough, because the compiler doesn't immediately realize it needs to coerce, and when it does it's too late (you can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72521801/7884305)). You need to hint it. A simple `as` will suffice: `|v| Box::new(v) as _`.

Comment: I didn't know this syntax existed! I always used `Box::<dyn T>::new(v)`

Comment: @ImajinDevon [You cannot do that](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=345b39c0ff62121398619fdd21f93650). And this syntax is nothing special, just `as` with inferred target type.

Comment: I've done something similar somewhere, I just can't find it.

Comment: Oh cool! My solution was to do `.map(|v| -> Box<dyn Animal> { Box::new(v) })`, but `as _` is nicer.

Comment: It's also worth noting that coercing a `Box<Dog>` into a `Box<dyn Animal>` is not a no-op, so it kinda makes sense that we have to be a little explicit sometimes.