# Composition and reusability in Rust compiled code

Tags: rust, memory-management, composition

I am new to the composition approach with Rust, and I am having a hard time trying to figure out whether I could make my code more efficient / smaller.

Let us assume that I have a base struct `BaseStruct`:

```rust
struct BaseStruct {
   values: Vec<i32>,
}
impl BaseStruct {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self{values: vec![]}
    }
}
```

Then, I define a `AsBase` trait to ease the composition process:

```rust
/ Trait used to do composition
trait AsBase {
   fn as_base(&mut self) -> &mut BaseStruct;
   // Note that add_val has a default implementation!
   fn add_val(&mut self, val: i32) {
       // let us assume that this method has hundreds of lines of code
       self.as_base().values.push(val);
   }
}
// Note that BaseStruct implements the AsBase trait!
impl AsBase for BaseStruct {
    fn as_base(&mut self) -> &mut BaseStruct {
        self
    }
}
```

Note that `BaseStruct` implements the `AsBase` trait! Otherwise, we couldn't add a value to the vector.
Then, I derive the behavior of the base struct using composition:

```rust
// Derived struct and handy functions
struct DerivedStruct {
   base: BaseStruct,
}
impl DerivedStruct {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self{base: BaseStruct::new()}
    }
}

// Derived struct also implements the AsBase trait
impl AsBase for DerivedStruct {
    fn as_base(&mut self) -> &mut BaseStruct {
        &mut self.base
    }
}
```

So now, I can add values to the inner vector of my derived struct using the trait method!

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut base = BaseStruct::new();
    base.add_val(1);
    
    let mut derived = DerivedStruct::new();
    derived.add_val(1); // With composition and AsBase trait, I achieve "inheritance"
}
```

[Here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=61860cfdfa393ebd93124de3a93de60a) you have a playground with this example.

However, what if the `add_val` default method was very complex and required hundreds of lines of code? Would Rust generate a different method `add_val` for every struct implementing the `AsBase` trait? Or is the compiler smart enough to detect that they can share the same function?

Let me try to be clearer: would this alternative implementation be smaller is size, as it explicitly uses the same method?

```rust
// Base struct and handy associated methods
struct BaseStruct {
   values: Vec<i32>,
}
impl BaseStruct {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self{values: vec![]}
    }
    fn add_val(&mut self, val: i32) {
    // Let us assume that this method is hundreds of lines long
        self.values.push(val);
    }
}

// Trait used to do composition
trait AsBase {
   fn as_base(&mut self) -> &mut BaseStruct;
   // Note that add_val has a default implementation!
   fn add_val(&mut self, val: i32) {
       self.as_base().add_val(val);
   }
}
// Note that BaseStruct does NOT implement the AsBase trait to avoid naming collision!

// Derived struct and handy functions
struct DerivedStruct {
   base: BaseStruct,
}
impl DerivedStruct {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self{base: BaseStruct::new()}
    }
}

// Derived struct also implements the AsBase trait
impl AsBase for DerivedStruct {
    fn as_base(&mut self) -> &mut BaseStruct {
        &mut self.base
    }
}


fn main() {
    let mut base = BaseStruct::new();
    base.add_val(1);
    
    let mut derived = DerivedStruct::new();
    derived.add_val(1); // With composition and AsBase trait, I achieve "inheritance"
}
```

(Also, note that I couldn't implement the `AsBase` trait for `BaseStruct` due to naming collisions, I don't know if there is a workaround to avoid this other than changing the names of the methods).

[Here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=59de3de419d37ea8164635859ae3ebb3) you have a playground for the alternative version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the compiler will generate a new instance of `add_val()` for each type. It may collapse them if they use the same machine code, but it will not if they don't. If you want to avoid that, a common way is to define a nested function (see [Why does std::fs::write(...) use an inner function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72246105/why-does-stdfswrite-use-an-inner-function/)):

```rust
fn add_val(&mut self, val: i32) {
    fn inner(this: &mut BaseStruct) {
        // let us assume that this method has hundreds of lines of code
        base.values.push(val);
    }
    inner(self.as_base());
}
```

However, what you're doing is not composition. Rather, it's emulating inheritance with composition. When using the composition principle, you should not (usually) have an `AsBase` trait because you should not treat `DerivedStruct` as `BaseStruct`. This is not "is-a" relationship, this is a "has-a" relationship. If a method needs a `BaseStruct`, pass it a reference to the field directly and let it perform its work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It is very clarifying