# Why repeat requires owned number?

Tags: rust, reference

Have a look at this code:

```rs
let some_number: usize = 5;

let some_string = "abc".repeat(&some_number);
```

I get compilation error:

> expected `usize`, found `&usize`

I wonder, is there any reason for `repeat` to require owned value for the number of repetitions? If I understand it correctly, if `repeat` would expect a reference, I'd be able to pass both `some_number` (Rust would automatically pass a reference) or `&some_number`. The experience would be better for the programmers.

Comment: When you don't need an owned value, it's best to pass a reference — except when the type is `Copy` (and small), since passing the value is cheaper and, like passing by reference, won't consume the value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First,

> if `repeat` would expect a reference, I'd be able to pass both `some_number` (Rust would automatically pass a reference) or `&some_number`

This is incorrect. Rust does autoreference in some cases (namely, in the receiver) but not all (other parameters). This falls under the "not all" case.

Second, taking a reference is more costly. If the caller already have an owned value, we need to store it in the stack (instead of a register), take a reference to it and the function needs to dereference it. This costs CPU instructions and cycles.

Third, it is not a big hassle to just dereference a reference you have before passing it. This only requires a small `*` at the front of the parameter.

The function could, theoretically, take `impl AsRef<usize>` or something like it. This will accept both owned values and references, but will have other costs: compile time, binary size ([which can be mitigated by adding an inner function and calling it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72246105/7884305), but again this costs in compile time and stdlib's development cost), inference, and all for the dubious benefit of saving an asterisk.